# Hermiticity of momentum space Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hamiltonian, two-level-system

I have managed to confuse myself with the notion of hermiticity in momentum space.

In most quantum mechanical applications we assume:
$$
H(R) = H^{\dagger}(R)
$$
For $R$ some position vector. Now expanding this $H(R)$ in momentum space (on some lattice) gives:
$$
H(R) = \sum_{k}e^{ikR}H(k)
$$
So that the hermiticity condition now translates to:
$$
H^{\dagger}(R) = \sum_k e^{-ikR}H^{\dagger}(k)=\sum_k e^{ikR}H^{\dagger}(-k) = \sum_k e^{ikR} H(k)=H(R)
$$
So that comparing gives directly that $H^{\dagger}(-k) = H(k)$.

Thus, for example, if we have a $2\times 2$ Hamiltonian $H(k)=\vec{d}(k)\cdot \sigma$ then:

\begin{equation}
\vec{d}(k)  = \vec{d}^*(-k)
\end{equation}

But isn't hermiticity a property of the vector space we operate in? Is not $H(k)$ an equally valid description of the physics, so that we should be able to impose hermiticity on $H(k)$, which would result in:
\begin{equation} 
\vec{d}(k) = \vec{d}^*(k)
\end{equation}

Is there anything special about position space here? Which of the last two equations holds?

Comment: Maybe you can clarify what $H(R)$ _is_? I have the impression that in your question $H(R)$ is _not_ the Hamiltonian itself, rather the Hamiltonian is $\mathcal{H} = \int \text{d} R\, \Psi_R^\dagger H(R) \Psi_R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion arises from using various "Hamiltonians": $H(R)$, $H(k)$.

These are not *the* Hamiltonian of the system $\mathcal{H}$, which for free particles on a lattice can be written
\begin{equation} \mathcal{H} = \sum_{R,R'} c_R^\dagger H(R-R') c_{R'} \tag{1}\end{equation}
where we just assumed homogeneity on the lattice.

Notice that imposing $\mathcal{H}^\dagger = \mathcal{H}$ leads to
\begin{equation} \tag{2} (H(R))^* = H(-R) \end{equation}
We can express Eq. (1) also in Fourier space as\begin{equation} \mathcal{H} = \sum_{K} c_k^\dagger H(k) c_{k} \tag{3} \end{equation}
where $H(k)$ is often called *Block Hamiltonian*.

Notice that from Eq. (2) it follows
$$ (H(k))^* = H(k) \tag{4} $$

Therefore the answer is: your last equation $d(k) = (d(k))^*$ is correct. Notice that your second last equation $d(k) = (d(-k))^*$ is also correct, if there is inversion symmetry. Finally, of course one can use either $H(R)$ or $H(k)$ to express the Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}$. Only $\mathcal{H}$ needs to be Hermitian.

Comment: Thank you, that clarified the issue!